# Access Methods of a class from created object of another class

Tags: java

I need little help here. I have three classes `Book`, `Member`, `Bean`.

Book.java

```
public class Book
{
  public Member m=null;
  // various getter & setter methods
}
```

Member.java

```
public class Member
{
  public Book b=null;
  // various getter & setter methods
}
```

In `Bean.java` I create an object of `Book` class & through this object we have to access all methods of Book as well as Member class.Now the problem is the object of Member class created in Book is not initialized & we can't use new operator to initialize it & we can't make it static. If we use new operator the result is not come.

Comment: _we can't use new operator to initialize_ why you can't? any reason for it?

Comment: If you don't want to use new operator for Member, just pass and assign its instance while creating Book.

Comment: Can you go for DI , like Spring DI ?

Comment: if i use new operator then result is not come. when i use null, only methods of Book class is work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This design is not correct.

There is a circular dependency.

`Book` has a `Member` and `Member` has a `Book` .

You need to double check this design.

Constructor injection would be the easiest way to fix this once you have the dependencies sorted out.

UPDATE : Corrected design which I feel is correct.

```
//Book  
public class Book {
   private String bookName;
   private String authorName;
   //getters and setters
}

//Member will have a book (maybe multiple) associated with them  
public class Member {
     private Book[] bookArray;
     public Member (Book... books) {
         this.bookArray = books;
     }
}
```

Comment: How? Please tell me solution. what is constructor injection ??

Comment: But in Book class can i able to create object in same way?? Actually in my project there is three actor CLERK, CUSTOMER, VENDOR. for this i need to access those classes from both side.

Comment: `Book` class will not have any dependency on `Member` . The same `Book` instance can be passed down to `Clerk` , `Customer` and `Vendor`.

Comment: if i made bookArray as private then the array cant access by object of member.

Comment: you can add a `getter` if needed for that.

Comment: With Member & Book Class I have to add two more classes Supply (for vendor who can supply the books) & Sales(for customer who can buy the book). In that case what will be the dependencies you think. I am confused that supply & sales how relate with Member class. do you have an idea??

Comment: Try drawing out the dependencies using a UML class diagram. That would clear your doubts.